# How to Add a Style Object to Each Icon in the Array?

Tags: reactjs

I want to send icons like component into another components and after give for all icons hover, but there have one problem, when i try to give hover for icons its not working or when hovering, all icons work at the same time, but not the one that was hovered over

Sorry I forgot to post the content of filterData here image from filterdata =>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxlxK.png)

```
import { Accordion } from './Accordion';
import { filterData } from '../../../../Shared/BazaData/filterData';

export const CollapseFilter = () => {

    const data = filterData.name.map((item, index) => {
        const Icon = filterData.icons[index]
        return (
            <>
                <div className='accordion'  >
                     <Accordion  icon={<Icon/>} data={item.name} />
                </div>
            </>
        )
    })
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div>
                    {data}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
    }


import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Down } from "../../../../Shared/icons/Down"

export const Accordion = ({ data, icon }) => {

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
    const [mouseover, setMouseover] = useState(false)
    
    const ChangeDownIconColor = {
        transform: isOpen ? 'rotate(180deg)' : '',
        transition: 'transform 180ms ease',
        fill: isOpen ? '#663FD7' : mouseover ? '#663FD7' : ''
    }
    const ChangeIconColor = {
        fill: isOpen ? '#663FD7' : mouseover ? '#663FD7' : ''
    }
    const ChangeDataTextColor = {
        color: isOpen ? '#663FD7' : mouseover ? '#663FD7' : ''
    }
  
    

    return (
        <>
            <div className="accordion_container" onMouseOver={() => setMouseover(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setMouseover(false)}  onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
                <button className="button_container"  >  
                    <div style={ChangeIconColor}>{icon}</div> 
                    <div className="title" style={ChangeDataTextColor} >{data}</div>
                </button>
                <Down style={ChangeDownIconColor}/>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtokd.png
```

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this. can you please post the contents of `filterData` ?

Comment: i edited my last post and add on the top where i explain my problem, link to filterData it is image